# Question about zlib decompress streaming data

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I want to know that if zlib can decompress streaming data.

For example, the gzip file is divided into three TCP segment(overlay is http) for transmission. Can I decompress the first, second, and third tcp segment separately to get the raw data?

My testing conclusion is that only after receiving the complete gzip file can decompression be performed correctly.

```
int http_content_decompress_write_zlib(struct http_content_decompress *decompress,
                                      const char *indata, size_t indata_len,
                                      char **outdata, size_t *outdata_len) {
z_stream *z_stream_ptr = decompress->z_stream_ptr;
z_stream_ptr->avail_in = (unsigned int)indata_len;
z_stream_ptr->next_in = (unsigned char *)indata;

*outdata = NULL;
*outdata_len = 0;

int ret = 0;
do {
    z_stream_ptr->avail_out = (unsigned int)decompress->buffer_size;
    z_stream_ptr->next_out = (unsigned char *)decompress->buffer;

    ret = inflate(z_stream_ptr, Z_NO_FLUSH);
    if (ret == Z_STREAM_ERROR || ret == Z_NEED_DICT
        || ret == Z_DATA_ERROR || ret == Z_MEM_ERROR) {
        printf("error msg:%s\n", z_stream_ptr->msg);
        //(void)inflateEnd(z_stream_ptr);
        //return -1;
    }

    size_t have = decompress->buffer_size - z_stream_ptr->avail_out;
    if (have > 0) {
        if (NULL == *outdata) {
            http_decoder_log(DEBUG, "%s alloc outbuffer %zu bytes", 
                             http_content_encoding_int2str(decompress->encoding),
                             have);
            *outdata = safe_dup(decompress->buffer, have);
            *outdata_len = have;
        } else {
            http_decoder_log(DEBUG, "%s realloc outbuffer %zu bytes", 
                             http_content_encoding_int2str(decompress->encoding), 
                             *outdata_len + have + 1);
            *outdata = REALLOC(char, *outdata, *outdata_len + have + 1);
            memcpy(*outdata + *outdata_len, decompress->buffer, have);
            *outdata_len = *outdata_len + have;
            memset(*outdata + *outdata_len, 0, 1);
        }
    } else {

    }
} while (0 == z_stream_ptr->avail_out);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Provide your code as text, please.

Answer (score 2):

Zlib is designed for streaming. It decompress the first segment and get all of the uncompressed data from that segment before anything else arrives. Then continue to decompress the second segment. And then the third.

Specifically, zlib cannot decompress the second segment until decompressing the first segment finished. The tcp segment must be decompressed in order.

The reason for the problem is that I create zlib decompression handle repeatly.

Comment: Please don't use the "Post Your Answer" button to submit content which does not attempt to answer the question at the top of this page. If you want to clarify your question, please (delete this and) edit it instead.

Comment: @tripleee I was about to write the same thing, but I think it is actually an answer to the question. _"Can I decompress the first, second, and third tcp segment separately to get the raw data?"_ - ... and the answer is then _"no"_. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two very different questions.

> I want to know that if zlib can decompress streaming data.

Yes, zlib can decompress streaming data. It was designed specifically for that purpose. You can read a chunk at a time and decompress a chunk at a time. There is never any need to have all of the compressed or decompressed data in memory at the same time. You can decompress an arbitrarily large compressed data stream with a small, constant amount of memory.

> Can I decompress the first, second, and third tcp segment separately
> to get the raw data?

No, not completely separately. You cannot, for example, process the second segment without having first processed the first segment. They must be processed in order.

You are not showing how you are using your code, but what must be done is to have a *single* inflate engine for all three segements, into which you feed the first segment, *then* the second segment, *then* the third segment. There would be one call of `inflateInit()`, as many calls of `inflate()` as needed to decompress all of the segments as they come in, and then one `inflateEnd()` call. (Or an `inflateReset()` to reuse the engine for a new stream.)